# Writing new angular service returns error Error: Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write a simple service following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/exclsr/3595424). The code for adding the new service is:

```
'use strict';
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);
projectModule.factory('Team', function() {  
    return {
        thing : {
            x : 100
        }
    };
});
```

My controller code is:

```
var Controllers = angular.module('fixedTeam',[]);
Controllers.controller('controller', function ($scope,$http,$location,Team) {
    $scope.getFixedTeam = function(){
        console.debug(Team.thing);
    }
});
```

When I load the view, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: TeamProvider <- Team
createInjector/providerInjector<@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:2734
getService@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:2862
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:2739
getService@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:2862
invoke@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:2880
instantiate@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:2914
@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:4805
update@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:14198
Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:8307
updateRoute/<@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:7463
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:6846
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:6846
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:6883
Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:8057 
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:7922 
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:8143 
done@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:9170 
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:9333 
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:9304
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify `Controllers` in your second snippet. How is it defined?

Comment: Controllers.controller should probably be projectModule.controller

Comment: @stevuu i have added it. "var Controllers = angular.module('fixedTeam',[]);

Comment: Then you need to add `projectModule` as a dependency as @Codezilla shows in his answer.

Comment: @stevuu it gives another error, kindly see comments on codezilla answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to add the dependent module:

```
var Controllers = angular.module('fixedTeam',['project']);
```

Comment: it gives me now "
Error: No module: projectModule
[Break On This Error]  

throw Error('No module: ' + name);